# Stick Control for Speed

Tags: drums

I've been working on fine tuning my finger control to increase speed and finesse. Here is the problem. My stick rotates in my left hand. It does not move forward or backwards, just rotates. The problem is it rotates then seems to roll to the tip of my thumb, which causes me to stop and re-grip. Visually, my grip looks identical in both hands. Yes, my left is weaker, but I feel like I'm holding both sticks with equal pressure. How might I stop that rotation and roll?

Thank you!

Doug

Answer (score 1):

I used to have exactly the same problem. In my case, one of the reasons was that my left hand do tend to slightly rotate inward - almost unnoticeably but enough to affect the stick rebound. Sadly there was no particular exercise to correct this but the obvious: Practice slow and focused, and practice also **full strokes without finger control**.

Focus on really feeling the rebound on the tip and raising the stick with the wrist movement being guided by the rebound, and not the other way around. Getting a good wrist stroke with a good rebound is key to a smooth transition into finger control, by feeling the rebound and starting to guide the stick back to the hitting surface with your fingers instead of the wrist.

Doing this exersice, slow and controlled, for a couple of hours straight (while you watch a movie) did drastically improve my finger control. After 3-5 movies you'll be pretty confident.